# Auto incrementar ID

Tags: java, spring-boot, arraylist

Necesito que cada vez que yo agregue un objeto nuevo en mi arrayList a su id se le sume 1 con respecto al anterior, mi arrayList esta quedando así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los ID siempre quedan en 0, este es mi controlador:

```
@PostMapping("/addConfigureCampaign")
public String addConfig(@ModelAttribute ConfigCampaign configCampaign, Model model) {
    listConfigCampaigns.add(configCampaign);
    return "redirect:/configureCampaign";
}
```

Esta mi es clase modelo:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int configid;
private String debtagerule;
private String remindebttype;
private int every;
private String unit;
private boolean selected;
//getters and setters
```

Nota: el arrayList solo esta en memoria, no persiste en ninguna base de datos.

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: podrias indicar que el id es igual `nombreDelArraylist.size()` eso te devuleve el tamaño del arrayList el cual se va incrementando a medida que le agregues un objeto

Comment: crea un contador y  a medida q vas insertando objetos le vas dando a su id  el valor de este contador y lo vas incrementando en 1